# Какой шаблон проектирования тут можно использовать?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Уже не первый раз попадается задача на работе, как та, что опишу ниже и я не знаю какой паттерн можно применить корректно. Может быть подскажите.

Условно так: в GET параметре прилетает тип (type) фигуры, которую нужно отрисовать. Неважно какая длина, ширина, диаметр и пр. Любой. Просто нужно отрисовать фигуру по типу. Их ограниченное количество. Я делаю так:

- Делаю абстрактный класс `Figure`, где есть `protected static $type = ''` и  абстрактный метод `render`
- Делаю несколько фигур, наследников от `Figure` , в которых переопределяю как свойство, так и метод.
  Получается что-то типа `SquareFigure extends Figure`, `CircleFigure extends Figure`, `TriangleFigure extends Figure` и т.д.
- А дальше, т.к. заранее тип неизместен, делаю `FigureManager` в котором есть мапа, из которой можно достать наименование класса по его типу:

  ```
    class FigureManager {

        public static function getFiguresMap() {
            return [
                SquareFigure::getType() => SquareFigure::class,
                CircleFigure::getType() => CircleFigure::class,
                TriangleFigure::getType() => TriangleFigure::class
            ];
        }
    }
  ```
- Теперь в нужно месте я пишу что-то типа такого:

  ```
    $figureType = $_GET['type'];

    $figureClassName = FigureManager::getFiguresMap()[$figureType];
    $figure = new $figureClassName();
    $figure->render();
  ```

Всё хорошо, но проблема в том, что есть какой-то класс, который знает о всех типах фигур. Хранит в себе мапу. И при добавлении новой, нужно добавлять туда ещё одну. Если фигур будет 4-5 - не страшно, а если 40-50? В общем, нормально ли делать так, я делаю? То есть выбора в данном случае нет? Или есть более практичный способ сделать это по феншую? Применить корректно какой-либо паттерн проектирования. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: либо менеджер знает про классы, либо классы знают про менеджер, что требует написания какого-нить, условно, `FigureManager::register(self)`. И зачем вам возвращать массив, а не вызывать какой-нить `FigureManager::getInstance($className)` ?

Comment: @teran я просто это смогла придумать :)  Тогда получается наверное не `FigureManager::getInstance($className)` а `FigureManager::getInstanceByType($type)` ? А то для первого варианта всё равно нужно этот класнейм брать откуда-то. Получается, что вариант нормальный, просто нужно чуть подшлифовать? А то я думала что что-то делаю не так если какой-то класс знает о всех наследниках своих или другого класса

Comment: "какой-то класс, который знает о всех типах фигур" - это вполне нормально. Гораздо проще хранить мапу объектов в **одном месте** и один раз вносить в нее изменения, чем таскать условный `switch(figureType) { new FigureType() }` по всему твоему коду и вносить изменения в десятки мест сразу. При дальнейшем развитии можно превратить все это в __фабрику__ или __фабричный метод__.

Comment: @u_mulder вот я знаю про фабрику и фабричный метод, но сделать я не смогла, потому что видимо они применимы только если знаешь конкретный тип в конкретный момент, а тут динамика. Или я просто не знаю как сделать в них при текущих условиях.

Comment: Если вы хотите всё на автомате, то вам понадобится сканер классов. Тогда ваш менеджер фигур сможет просканировать код на предмет классов фигур и их тип, например, через аннотации над классом. Если же вы не сталкивались со сканером, то у вас вполне себе рабочий код.

Comment: @ArchDemon Поняла, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас прикладная задача

> В общем, нормально ли делать так

В общем да, почему нет, если у вас только 1 класс будет работать с
этим перечнем, то ок.

Если много, то это уже фи. Вы сами со временем загнетесь добавлять везде, и вспомните про O из солида

---

Ваш код можно немножко улучшить, если переписать под фабрику:

```php
  $figureType = $_GET['type'];

  $figure = FigureFactory::getFigure(figureType);
  $figure->render();
```

---

+, так же в вопросе вы это не указали, от себя добавлю, что тип фигуры было бы круто загнать в Enum, типа https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum

```php
  $figureType = FigureType::from($_GET['type']);

  $figure = FigureFactory::getFigure(figureType);
  $figure->render();
```

Comment: Да, перечисления было бы неплохо, но сейчас вся их реализация очень костыльная. Ждём  php 8.1 :)

Comment: @Иришка ну, если вам позволяет ситуация юзать новейшую версию языка, то ок, если нет, то юзайте указанную либу, она отлично себя показала в практике